# How correctly to make controllers to routes in Golang?

Tags: go

I am new in **Golang** and need some help. I am tring to create REST API web service without ORM.

Right now I am successfully connected to **PostgreSQL** database. In database I have table which called `factors`. I want to create CRUD operations. The problem is with controllers logic.

**main.go**:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "rest_api/configurations"
    "rest_api/controllers"
)

func main()  {
    db, err := configurations.PostgreSQLDatabase()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    router := mux.NewRouter()

    router.StrictSlash(true)

    subrouter := router.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()

    subrouter.HandleFunc("/factors", controllers.GetFactors(db)).Methods("GET")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))
}
```

**models/factors.go**:

```
package models

type Factor struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

How correctly looks like the `GetFactors` controller? Can someone show me please. For instance I pass `db` object to `GetFactors` controller as in the example below. Unfortunately it seems like it's incorrect.

**controllers/factors.go**:

```
func GetFactors(db *sql.DB, w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // some code
}
```

**configurations/PostgreSQL.go**:

```
func PostgreSQLDatabase() (*sql.DB, error) {
    // Load environment variables from ".env" file.
    err := godotenv.Load(".env")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Initialize database-related variables.
    dbUser := os.Getenv("PostgreSQL_USER")
    dbPassword := os.Getenv("PostgreSQL_PASSWORD")
    dbHost := os.Getenv("PostgreSQL_HOST")
    dbName := os.Getenv("PostgreSQL_DB_NAME")
    dbURL := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s host=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", dbUser, dbPassword, dbHost, dbName)

    // Create PostgreSQL database connection pool.
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbURL)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Ping PostgreSQL database to make sure it's alive.
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("Web service successfully connected to remote PostgreSQL database.")
    }

    return db, nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern I like to use is to define your own `Router` struct that has a `mux.Router` as a field as well as encapsulates things like your database connection, application config and etc.

I find doing it this way makes it easily update your routes when they require different resources and development proceeds.

First create a router object that takes in the database connection on creation and makes it available to all routes you wish to use.

**router.go**

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "database/sql"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Router struct {
    router *mux.Router
    db *sql.DB
}

func NewRouter(db *sql.DB) (*Router, error) {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.StrictSlash(true)
    subrouter := router.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()

    r := &Router{
        router: router,
        db: db,
    }

    subrouter.HandleFunc("/factors", r.GetFactors).Methods(http.MethodGet)

    return r, nil
}

func (r *Router) GetFactors(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // Now you can access your database via `r.db`
}

// Needed so we can pass our custom router to ListenAndServe.
func (r *Router) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    r.router.ServeHTTP(w, req)
}
```

Then in `main.go` you can simply create your custom router, passing it your database connection. Then the custom router can be passed directly to `ListenAndServe`.

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "rest_api/configurations"
    "rest_api/controllers"
)

func main()  {
    db, err := configurations.PostgreSQLDatabase()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    router, err := NewRouter(db)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error initializing router: %v", err)
    }

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I think your advised more structured way. I have one more question. Lets say I want to put `GetFactors` function in a separate file. How I need to pass `Router` struct which is inside `router.go` file?!

Comment: Typically I would put the `Router` struct and its methods (i.e `GetFactors`) into its own `router` package. Then you can put them in separate files so long as they have the same package name at the top of the file. Since `GetFactors` has the `Router` struct as its receiver you wouldn't need to explicitly pass it to `GetFactors`.

Comment: In the future it would be too much functions inside `router.go` file for each route. It will swell. I don't want to keep everything in one file. Lets say I create `controllers` folder (`package controllers`). Inside that folder create `factors.go` file and put next code: `func (r *Router) GetFactors(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {}` Golang don't see `r *Router` struct. Don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: `Router` and `GetFactors` need to be in the same package, but do not need to be in the same file. Create a `controllers` folder, then have a `router.go` and a `factors.go` file in that folder each with `package controllers` at the top, then `GetFactors` can see Router, but wont need to be in the same file.

Answer (score 2):

Your func `GetFactors` must looks like:

```
func GetFactors(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}
```

and in main file you must have:

```
subrouter.HandleFunc("/factors", controllers.GetFactors).Methods("GET")
```

and with purpose to get DB connection you must have func like `GetDB` in your package `"rest_api/configurations"`.

In `"rest_api/configurations"` you must have something like:

```
var db *PostgreSQLDatabase

func init() {
    var err error
    db, err = configurations.PostgreSQLDatabase()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func GetDB() *PostgreSQLDatabase {
  return db
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for you answer. Can you check my post again please?! I think my `PostgreSQLDatabase` function and your `GetDB` function are close. They both return database object. If I want to run SQL query inside `GetFactors` controller, do I need to pass a database object to that controller to execute the sql query? Isn't it? It's not clear from your code how I can make sql query inside `GetFactors` controller.

Comment: funcs `PostgreSQLDatabase` & `GetDB` must be separated. In `PostgreSQLDatabase` before `return db, nil` you have assign db value to `db` var from you package and return this value from func `GetDB`.

Comment: Ok, I will separate them, no problem. What would be next? I will call `GetDB` function inside `GetFactors` controller, right? It steal unclear for me what would be inside `GetFactors` controller...

Answer (score 2):

There is no correct way, it mostly opinion-based.

The semantic of HandlerFunc function should be like `func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)`, in order to pass database you can use closures, here is an example.

#### main.go

```
// ... some code here 
subrouter.HandleFunc("/factors", controllers.GetFactors(db)).Methods("GET")
// ... some code here
```

#### controllers/factors.go

```
func GetFactors(db *sql.DB) http.HandlerFunc {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // some code
  })
}
```

Another option:

I'm not quite sure about this, but you can adjucts it to your needs. Initialize a `Controller` struct and pass db to it:

#### main.go

```
// ... some code here 
db, err := configurations.PostgreSQLDatabase()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
ctrl := controllers.Controller{DB: db}
subrouter.HandleFunc("/factors", ctrl.GetFactors).Methods("GET")
// ... some code here
```

Denote a method on the Controller struct.
Define a struct in the controllers

#### controllers/factors.go

```
type Controller struct {
  DB *PostgreSQLDatabase
}

func (c Controller) GetFactors(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // some code
    // c.DB.MySqlMethod()
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I am not sure is it best practice what I am tring to do. As you can see I pass database object to `GetFactors` function. I make it only with one task. I want to run SQL query inside `GetFactors` controller. How do you think is it correct what I am tring to do or you can advice more elegant way?

Comment: I think it's good design because it is avoid declaration of global variable(db in this case), there is also another option, you can define a struct with database and declare GetFactors on that method.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear for me your another option. Can you show me little example please?